# Multi line/unknown data regex query

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a text data set coming to me that I need to parse out into multiple "groups". The groups are a numeric identifier. The issue I am having, is that each "CUSTOMER" in this dataset has an unknown set of data and an number of additional lines with it after the initial two lines used to identify them.

For example:

```
CUSTOMER|100000|Last|First|20171200-000000|20171200-000000|||||||||||||N|||
PAYMENTS|||1234|1234|20171200-000000|20171200-000000||||||||||||1||||
REBOUND||||||||||
INFO||||||||||
CUSTOMER|100001|Last|First|20171200-000000|20171200-000000|||||||||||||N|||
PAYMENTS|||1234|1234|20171200-000000|20171200-000000||||||||||||142||||
INFO||||||||||
CUSTOMER|100002|Last|First|20171200-000000|20171200-000000|||||||||||||N|||
PAYMENTS|||1234|1234|20171200-000000|20171200-000000||||||||||||1||||
INFO||||||||||
PRE||||||||||
INFO||||||||||
```

So in this example, I want to delete CUSTOMERS with a value of 142. The value of 142 can be seen in the PAYMENTS line near the end for CUSTOMER 100001.

I have been using Ruby, but I am willing to use whatever to get this done. So initially, I wrote this:

```
CUSTOMER\|.*\|142\|.+?(?=\nCUSTOMER)
```

Using the m flag, this looks for CUSTOMER, then looks for |142| then does a positive lookahead until it sees CUSTOMER again. The issue with this, is that regex is identifying off of the initial CUSTOMER found (100000) and continuing down the file until it finds |142| and then stopping. What I need is for the regex to stop if it sees the word CUSTOMER again before it sees |142|

I tried to add a negative look ahead after the

```
 CUSTOMER\|.*(?!CUSTOMER)
```

But this still gave me the full result. Im not sure how negative lookahead works with a greedy character match, but I assumed it would say "this isnt a match if at some point I find this point of failure"

Since then Ive tried a few other solutions, played around a bit with this:

```
(?!.*(?:\|142\|))
```

But ive gotten nowhere with it as well. Im still getting stuck on preventing the first CUSTOMER from grouping into the second. Thoughts?

Comment: The biggest identification question is where to find the `|142|` because it might be anywhere from customer to customer. Once that's settled you can do a good regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in two steps rather than one. That makes the solution easier to understand, test and maintain, and probably [is a wash](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/it's%20a%20wash) efficiency-wise.

First, let `str` hold the string that is read from a file.

```
str =<<BITTER_END
CUSTOMER|100000|Last|First|20171200-000000|20171200-000000|||||||||||||N|||
PAYMENTS|||1234|1234|20171200-000000|20171200-000000||||||||||||1||||
REBOUND||||||||||
INFO||||||||||
CUSTOMER|100001|Last|First|20171200-000000|20171200-000000|||||||||||||N|||
PAYMENTS|||1234|1234|20171200-000000|20171200-000000||||||||||||142||||
INFO||||||||||
CUSTOMER|100002|Last|First|20171200-000000|20171200-000000|||||||||||||N|||
PAYMENTS|||1234|1234|20171200-000000|20171200-000000||||||||||||1||||
INFO||||||||||
PRE||||||||||
INFO||||||||||
BITTER_END
```

The first step uses a regular expression to split `str` into an array of strings, each string corresponding to one of the customers.

```
r = /
    (?<=^)          # Match a beginning of line anchor in a positive lookbehind
    (?=CUSTOMER\|)  # Match 'CUSTOMER|' in a positive lookahead
    /x              # Free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Notice that when used with [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html), this regex breaks the string *between* characters, namely, after a newline character and before the string `'CUSTOMER|'`.

I've used free-spacing mode to make the regex self-documenting. Conventionally, it would be written

```
r = /(?<=^)(?=CUSTOMER\|)/
```

Now let's split `str` into groups.

```
a0 = str.split(r)
```

To make it easier to see the return value, let me print each element of `a0` separately.

```
a0.size.times { |i| puts "\n#{a0[i]}" } 

CUSTOMER|100000|Last|First|20171200-000000|20171200-000000|||||||||||||N|||
PAYMENTS|||1234|1234|20171200-000000|20171200-000000||||||||||||1||||
REBOUND||||||||||
INFO||||||||||

CUSTOMER|100001|Last|First|20171200-000000|20171200-000000|||||||||||||N|||
PAYMENTS|||1234|1234|20171200-000000|20171200-000000||||||||||||142||||
INFO||||||||||

CUSTOMER|100002|Last|First|20171200-000000|20171200-000000|||||||||||||N|||
PAYMENTS|||1234|1234|20171200-000000|20171200-000000||||||||||||1||||
INFO||||||||||
PRE||||||||||
INFO||||||||||
```

The second step removes the elements of `a0` that contain the string `'|142|'`.

```
a1 = a0.reject { |s| s.include?('|142|') }
```

a1.size.times { |i| puts "\n#{a1[i]}" }

```
CUSTOMER|100000|Last|First|20171200-000000|20171200-000000|||||||||||||N|||
PAYMENTS|||1234|1234|20171200-000000|20171200-000000||||||||||||1||||
REBOUND||||||||||
INFO||||||||||

CUSTOMER|100002|Last|First|20171200-000000|20171200-000000|||||||||||||N|||
PAYMENTS|||1234|1234|20171200-000000|20171200-000000||||||||||||1||||
INFO||||||||||
PRE||||||||||
INFO||||||||||
```

We would of course chain these two steps in the usual way.

```
str.split(r).reject { |s| s.include?('|142|') }
```

Tack `.join` onto the end of the above if the return value is to be a string. (That's not clear to me from the statement of the question.)

Comment: Thanks for the work you put into this and breaking it all down!

Breaking it down into individual elements eliminated the complexity around trying to do it all in regex and this provides a very easy/elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is pattern which seems to be working, at least when tested in a demo:

```
CUSTOMER((?!\nCUSTOMER).)*?\|142\|.*?(?=\nCUSTOMER)
```

Here is an explanation:

```
((?!\nCUSTOMER).)*?   Using a tempered dot, consume anything so long as
                      we do not encounter `\nCUSTOMER` on the next line
\|142\|               Match `|142|` somewhere inside the line
.*?(?=\nCUSTOMER)     Then consume the rest of the line up to CUSTOMER
```

### Demo

Note from the demo that my regex has a flaw.  If the `CUSTOMER` to be deleted happens to be the last one in the file, the regex would miss it, because there would be no beginning `CUSTOMER` after that.

Hopefully this is at least a good starting point for you.